# Intellij Idea thinks Spring project is Android project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a gradle spring java project setup, after weeks of it working, Idea suddenly thinks it is an android project, keeps asking me for Android SDK, after deleting .gradle and out/ folders and setting JDK in settings, it compiles and starts, but doesn't copy application.properties file that is required to run the app. Tried restarting, deleting .gradle, .idea, and any other output folder that I could find, but it seems like the only solution that temporarily helps is to clone the repository to a new folder. My suspicion is that I have something in my gradle file that tricks idea to think it's android, but couldn't find anything.

My build.gradle

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin

buildscript {
    ext {
        springVersion = "4.3.12.RELEASE"
        springBootVersion = '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("io.ebean:ebean-gradle-plugin:11.34.1")
    }
}

apply plugin: SpringBootPlugin

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'io.ebean'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.3m")

    implementation('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.5')
    runtime "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.10.5", "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.10.5"

    implementation("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:${springVersion}")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1")

    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5")
    implementation("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:9.0.8")

    implementation("io.ebean:ebean:11.36.1")
    implementation("io.ebean:ebean-agent:11.11.1")
    implementation("io.ebean:ebean-spring-txn:11.10.4")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:'4.+")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean IDE project specific files and regenerate them with

```
./gradlew cleanIdea idea
```

Then try to import project again.

Comment: Seems like this and invalidating caches worked. Didn't work at first, but the second time I tried this together with invalidating, restarting and deleting (again) ~/.gradle worked.